# Http status -1 using $http

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing an Angular application and I'm using the default $httpService for the http requests.

The application run correctly on all my devices but not on my [G]old Samsung Galaxy s2 (using the default browser).

On the first request I get the following error:

```
{ 
  "data":null, 
  "status":-1, 
  "config": {
    "method":"GET", 
    "transformRequest":[null], 
    "transformResponse":[null],
    "url":"http://....",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Authorization": "Basic ....."
      } 
    },
  "statusText":""
}
```

I'm not able to figure out where the problem is.

The code is the following:

```
this.http.get(WebServices.localizations + this.currentLanguage.locale), success => {
            var localizationsJson = <any[]>success.data;
            var localizations = {};

            ....
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code in which you make the request?

Comment: I0m using the get method of the http service, however I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Is it making a CORS call?

Comment: Yes, it is making a CORS call

Comment: hi @user3471528 did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

There was a change in the more recent versions of angular, with the handling of http status code 0.

[Here is a github discussion based on the change.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12920)

I hope you have already solved you problem by now!